# Submit button not working in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I have been trying to make this work but the submit button is not working at all.
The bootstrap tab window I am using is:

```html
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add new Game</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                       <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Game Title</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" name="gtitle" />
                      </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">YouTube Link</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="" name="ytlink" />
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Link Source</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="ex: GLEAM, DLH, FAILMID, HRKGAME, INDIEGALA, OTHER, STEAM" name="slink" />
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Link to Free Steam Keys</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="KEY MUST GIVE +1 TO THE STEAM LIBRARY GAME COUNT" name="keysl" />
                       </div>
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Steam App ID</label>     
                       <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                       <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">http://store.steampowered.com/app/</span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="App ID" name="appid" />
                       </div>  
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Categories</label>
                         <div class="checkbox">
                    
                            <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" /> 1 <h4><span class="label label-success">Keys Available</span></h4>
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" /> 2 <h4><span class="label label-danger">No Keys left</span></h4>
</label>

                      
                       </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert">Submit</button>
                       </div>
   
                        </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">abc</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">..</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...dd</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've tried to use and javascript.. even that not working..
Whenever I click the submit buttons, nothing happens and the form doesn't post the values. Let me know how to make this work.

Comment: I rolled your question back to its original state. There's no need to remove the code you had and replaced it with "SOLVED". Accepting an answer marks it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<form>` tag instead in your `form-group` to submit a form.

Do these instead:

```
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="submit_something.php">
.
.
.
</form>
```

And you might need PHP for handling form submit to your database, if there is.

Answer (score 2):

Submit buttons submit FORMS. Where is your `form` tag?

You need a form tag with a method and an action:

```
<form action="/form-post-url" method="post">
```

Comment: wow.. I'm so dumb.. this was the problem.. thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to surround your "form" with form tags.

```
<form role="form"> </form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp